# Affine Weyl group as Coxeter group

Tags: combinatorics, lie-algebras, root-systems

How do you write the affine Weyl group corresponding to type $A_n$ as a Coxeter group ? The generators are $s_0,s_1,\dots,s_n$ where $s_0$ corresponds to the highest root. What are all the relations ? What are all the positive roots in this case?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coxeter%E2%80%93Dynkin_diagram

Comment: What are the relations between $s_0$ and other $s_i$'s ?

Comment: I would recommend checking a copy of "James E. Humphreys, Reflection Groups and Coxeter Groups, Cambridge studies in advanced mathematics, 29 (1990)" out of your library. Humphreys' text is quite readable and has the details you need.